# Why are we solving this integral in this specific fashion?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry

I am solving the following problem:
$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{(x^2*\sqrt{1+x^2})}$

I set $x = \tan(\theta)$

$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}\theta} = \sec^2(\theta)$

$\int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\tan^2(\theta)*\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}}*\text{d}x$

$\int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\tan^2(\theta)*\sec(\theta)} *\text{d}\theta$

After some simplifying I get: $\int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)} * \text{d}\theta$

$u = \sin(\theta)$

$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}\theta} = \cos(\theta)$

$\int \frac{\text{d}u}{u^2}$

$\frac{-1}{\sin(\theta)} + c$

*It is here where I get confused*

[image: Triangle used to get answer: Triangle 1]

[image: Second trianlge: Triangle 2]

**If you use the first triangle: $\sin(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$**

**If you use the second triangle: $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$**

Could I use either one to find my answer in terms of x? My theory is that we use the first triangle because $x = \tan(\theta)$ and using the first triangle we get $x = \frac{x}{1}$ compared to $x = \frac{1}{x}$ This makes $x$ true for all real numbers in the first one while $x$ can only be equal to 1 in the second equation.

Is this right or no? Sorry for making this question so long.

Comment: Only the first triangle agrees with your substitution $\tan(\theta)=x$. In the second one, $\tan(\theta)=\frac1x$, or $\cot(\theta)=x$. That said, you can still compute the integral by substituting $\cot(\theta)=x$ instead, and you'll end up with the same antiderivative (up to a constant)

Comment: @user170231 Okay. Thank you. This helps a lot.